# Is there any way to call trigger explicity in oracle?

Tags: oracle, triggers

Can trigger can be explicitly called ?
I got question like

Trigger can be

a)Implicit

b)Explicit

c)Both

Is there any way to call Trigger Externally ?

Comment: What is "internal" and "external" call in this context?

Comment: Like Procedures to execute is there any way to call triggers by code (explicity)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [first paragraph of the overview of triggers](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/triggers.htm#LNPLS2001) (emphasis added):

> Like a stored procedure, a trigger is a named PL/SQL unit that is stored in the database and can be invoked repeatedly. Unlike a stored procedure, you can enable and disable a trigger, but ***you cannot explicitly invoke it***.

So no, a trigger cannot be explicitly called.